# setText doesn't work properly if the string starts with a negative sign

Tags: java, string, swing, calculator, jtextfield

So, i am making a calculator. I was trying to display the equation in a JTextField, but the equation doesn't print correctly if it starts with a negative sign.

```
textfield.setText("-3+3");
```

gives output = 3+3-

but the same equation when in

```
System.out.println("-3+3");
```

gives output in the correct order

sorry if it is some noob mistake.

EDIT:

```
package practice;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class fun extends JFrame implements ActionListener , FocusListener{


public static void main(String[] args){

    new fun();
}

JTextField display2 = new JTextField(20);

JTextField display = new JTextField(20);

JButton btnSol = new JButton("=");

public fun(){

    JFrame fr = new JFrame();

    fr.setSize(450,450);

    fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    fr.setResizable(false);

    fr.setTitle("Calculator");

    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();


    display.setEditable(false);
    display2.setEditable(false)

    pnl.add(display);

    pnl.add(display2);

    pnl.add(btnSol);

    btnSol.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String x = display2.getText();
            System.out.println(x);
            display.setText(x);
            int sum = 0;
            String[] arrOfStr = x.split("\\+");                   
            for (String a : arrOfStr) {
                System.out.println(a);

            sum += Integer.parseInt(a);
            display2.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
            }

        }
    });

    fr.add(pnl);
    fr.setVisible(true);


}
```

Comment: Are you instantiating a JTextField or a JFormattedTextField?

Comment: i am using a JTextField as a display

Comment: By output you mean what is displayed inside the text field?

Comment: yes, when I display it in the text field the minus sign moves to the end of the string whereas if i print it in console the order is corrrect.

Comment: I've just tried. Doesn't happen, and **shouldn't** happen. Could you post the entire class you're running?

Comment: Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So all you need is a JFrame with a JTextField to demonstrate how you use the setText() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you've set

```
textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Pretty simple. That's usually used for Arabic text (?), which I suppose is inverted.

Comment: ohhhh...thank you soo much... but, the digits get printed just fine

Comment: ohk wait got it because the its digits and characters. ohhhh. thank you sir.